# R corrplot change data labels

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am using R corrplot library. It looks amazing, however to produce a really good plot I want to change the labels of rows and columns of the correlation matrix.

One solution is to do something like this:

```
cbak <- colnames(my.data.frame)
colnames(my.data.frame) <- c("a", "set", "of", "labels")
corrplot(cor(my.data.frame))
colnames(my.data.frame) <- cbak
```

However this looks strange and ugly.

I guess I should work with the `labels` parameter of a `text()` function, but I can't figure how.

```
corrplot(cor(my.data.frame), labels=c("a", "set", "of", "labels"))
```

results in

```
Error in text.default(pos.xlabel[, 1], pos.xlabel[, 2], newcolnames, srt = tl.srt,  : 
  invalid 'pos' value
In addition: Warning message:
In text.default(pos.xlabel[, 1], pos.xlabel[, 2], newcolnames, srt = tl.srt,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the current `corrplot` version 0.75, you cannot use `labels` parameter because the X and Y labels are computed within the `corrplot()` function from `colnames()` and `rownames()` of the input `corr` matrix.

I'm using similar approach as you have suggested:

```
M <- cor(mtcars)
colnames(M) <- c("a", "set", "of", "x", "labels", 1:6)
corrplot(M, method = "color")
```

BTW, I linked this stackoverflow question from our github issue tracker:
https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/issues/20

**UPDATE:**
In the current `corrplot` version 0.78, also plotmath expressions are allowed in variable names. Just prefix your name with one of the characters ":", "=" or "$".

**Example:**

```
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:5,1:5]
colnames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", ":alpha+beta", ":a[0]", "=a[beta]")
rownames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", NA, "$a[0]", "$ a[beta]")
corrplot(M)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why when I run your code example on my console, subscripts do not appear in labels? Should I set something before?

Comment: OK, I did not see the UPDATE. It now works in the latest pre-release version available (version 0.82)

Comment: Is it possible to show only values > 0, for example?