# Math Symbols in corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

In my opinion this is one of the R stuff which is annoying. Some stuff is not logic or at least intuitively doable.

Now in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965433/r-corrplot-change-data-labels), the usage of greek symbols in corrplot was nicely explained. However what I can't get running is the other way around with first a greek letter and than normal text. E.g. 
   `colnames(data_matrix)[2] <- c(":Delta")`
or
   `colnames(data_matrix)[2] <- c("=S1P[Delta]")`

are working fine. 
However putting the Delta BEFORE the text is not working for me. Any suggestion on this?

After playing around I found this solution: 
`colnames(data_mat)[2] <- c(":Delta [S1P]")` so its logical and simple after all.

Now, one remaining problem is an empty space. I can write `colnames(data_mat)[2] <- c(":Delta [S1P]")` but not `colnames(data_mat)[2] <- c(":Delta [S 1P]")`

Any suggestions on this particular problem?