# How to include "superscript +" in corrplot label?

Tags: r, label, superscript, r-corrplot

I want to include "+" as a superscript in corrplot label. I was able to find ways to put subscript but not superscript. Any help would be really appreciated. Here is a simple example I found and I changed a little to make it relevant to my problem. [R corrplot change data labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965433/r-corrplot-change-data-labels/36190501#comment74036841_36190501)

I want a^+(+ as superscript) and a^2(a-squared) as 4th and 5th column names.

```
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:5,1:5]
colnames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", ":alpha+beta", ":a^[+]", ":a^[2]")
rownames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", NA, "$a[0]", "$ a[beta]")
corrplot(M)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put it in single quotes:

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.84 loaded
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:5,1:5]
colnames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", ":alpha+beta", ":a^'+'", ":a^2")
rownames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", NA, "$a[0]", "$ a[beta]")
corrplot(M)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>